# Все сообщения попадают в статус frozen

Tags: email, sendmail, exim

У меня не отправляются сообщения с помощью стандартной функции php mail(). Выполнив проверку с помощью команды exim оказалось, что все сообщения попадают в frozen. Подскажите пожалуйста по какой причине так происходит?

Comment: в логе смотрите.

Answer (score 0):

> по какой причине так происходит?

это может происходить из-за огромного количества причин. начиная от ошибок в конфигурации и заканчивая тем, что сообщения от вас просто не принимают (об этом будет написано в лог-файле).

проверка конфигурации (если есть ошибки в конф. файле, об этом будет написано):

```
$ sudo exim -bV
```

если конфигурационный файл не содержит ошибок, то дальше смотрите лог-файл.

если не знаете, где он находится, спросите у самой программы (приведён пример ответа):

```
$ sudo exim -bP log_file_path
log_file_path = /var/log/exim4/%slog
```

Comment: В конфиг. файле ошибок нет, в /var/log/exim/main.log обнаружил Message is frozen. Скажите пожалуйста куда дальше копать?